# HTML - PHP - AJAX send data issue

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

My HTML Code:

```
<form action="process.php" method="POST" class="appointment">
<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required="" placeholder="Adınız">
<input type="text" name="surname" class="form-control" required="" placeholder="Soyadınız">
<input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" required="" placeholder="Cep Telefonunuz">
<input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="eMail Adresiniz">
<select name="service" required="" class="form-control" onchange="getPersonnels(this.value);">
    <option value="">1) Lütfen hizmet seçin</option>
    <option value="1">Klinik Diyet</option>
    <option value="2">Online Diyet</option>
    <option value="3">Klinik Psikolojik Destek</option>
    <option value="4">Online Psikolojik Destek</option>
    <option value="5">Fitness</option>
</select>
<select name="personnel" required="" id="personnels" class="form-control" onchange="getPersonnelWorkingDays(this.value);">
    <option value="">2) Lütfen önce hizmet seçin</option>
</select>
<select name="date" required="" id="personnel-date" class="form-control" onchange="getPersonnelWorkingDaysHours(this.value);">
    <option value="">3) Lütfen önce danışman seçin</option>
</select>
<select name="clock" required="" id="personnel-date-hours" class="form-control">
    <option value="">4) Lütfen önce gün seçin</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="create-appointment" value="Randevu Oluştur" class="btn btn-secondary py-3 px-4">
```

And my js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getPersonnels(val) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ajax.php?getPersonnels",
        data:'service='+val,
        success: function(data){
            $("#personnels").html(data);
        }
    });
}

function getPersonnelWorkingDays(val) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ajax.php?getPersonnelWorkingDays",
        data:'personnel='+val,
        success: function(data){
            $("#personnel-date").html(data);
        }
    });
}

function getPersonnelWorkingDaysHours(val) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ajax.php?getPersonnelWorkingDaysHours",
        data:'personnel'+val,
        success: function(data){
            $("#personnel-date-hours").html(data);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

ajax.php include:

```
<?
if(isset($_GET['getPersonnelWorkingDaysHours'])){
    /* Test block, i'll code here when i catch the value */
    <option><? echo $_POST['personnel']; ?></option> 
}
?>
```

So you see, I want to catch value from name of "personnel" and id of "personnels", other functions are running when i request to the ajax page. But this function couldn't.
I think this problem is caused by

```
data:'personnel'+val,
```

line of my js.

Whats your idea ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should pass personnel data as **data:{personnel:val}**. Concatenating personnel and data is sending one string which is personnel... where ... is val and hence personnel ceases to exist as an attribute.

Comment: Unfortunately it's returning value of #personnel-date still.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Because from your PHP side, you are only processing the received data if the GET attribute  getPersonnelWorkingDaysHours was set. Meaning the request is coming from the getPersonnelWorkingDaysHours(val) function.